# .htaccess HTTP_USER_AGENT not working

Tags: android, ios, html, .htaccess, video

I'm having problems the .htaccess file, normally it checks the user referer and if is from my site it allows the access to stream mp4 files, but now I want to allow the streaming to Android and iOS devices, I'm using html5  tag but it doesn't send http_referer so I want to check the user agent to allow the stream of the mp4 files, this is what I have but it just doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Android|iPod|iPhone|iPad" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(direct\.|www\.)?mysite\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(mp4)$ http://www.mysite.com [R,NC]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a negation here, so you have to lose the `[OR]` and include a `!`:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(Android|iPod|iPhone|iPad) [NC]
```

What your rule is doing is redirecting **when it is not the correct referer and is not a mobile user-agent**. What you had before:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(direct\.|www\.)?mysite\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(mp4)$ http://www.mysite.com [R,NC]
```

Is saying: If the referer **isn't** from `http://(direct\.|www\.)?mysite\.com/`, then redirect the .mp4 request to `http://www.mysite.com`. The logic here is if the referer is correct, they can get to the mp4 file just fine.

To follow the logic where you say if the referer is correct *or* if the user-agent is mobile, serve the mp4, you need to negate the entire thing. `(A or B)-> do something`, to `!(A or B) -> don't do something`, which translates to: `!A and !B -> don't do something`.

So you need to negate the mobile user-agent check and instead of an **OR** use an **AND** (which is what is default for rewrite conditions).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Android|iPod|iPhone|iPad) [NC,OR]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was using the wrong syntax, your anwser just need a ! like Jon Lin said.

Comment: @Shixons I was just looking at the syntax and not the logic, will be more diligent next time.